# objective C what should I do for making these function threadsafe?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety

Here is the case.
I got a singleton class call DBManager with sqlite3. And insert,delete,select are done via this class.
suppose now ClassA need to insert a record to table a and ClassB need to select a record from table a. So the presudo code is like this.

```
Class A
[[DBManager getInstance] insertRecord:@"12345"];

Class B
-(void)processData{
    Record r = [[DBManager getInstance] getRecord];
    // working with record r. after that doing some layout update
    [self.lbTitle setText:r.name];
}
```

cause in my project, there are 4-5 class will access the db. So sometime a Database is locked error is throw and my app crashed.
I know one of the solution is using GCD dispatch_async(CUSTOM_DB_QUEUE,block)
using these block for all the codes related to the db.
But if so, i need to also modify Class B like this. Am I right?

```
Class B
-(void)processData{
   dispatch_async(CUSTOM_DB_QUEUE,{
   [[DBManager getInstance] getRecord onRecordGot:^(Record* r) {
       // working with record r. after that doing some layout update
       dispatch_async(MAIN_QUEUE,{
       [self.lbTitle setText:r.name];
       )};
    }];
)};
}
```

Is this approach correct?? so i need to change all my code in DBManager to return the result using block coding??
Is there any simple way for queue up the hold DBManager class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better approach. Do not make any changes to your code that calls `DBManager`. All changes should be made inside your `DBManager` class. And there is no reason to use `dispatch_async`. Use `dispatch_sync`.

This code stays the same:

```
Class A
[[DBManager getInstance] insertRecord:@"12345"];

Class B
-(void)processData{
    Record r = [[DBManager getInstance] getRecord];
    // working with record r. after that doing some layout update
    [self.lbTitle setText:r.name];
}
```

In your `insertRecord:` method you change it to something like:

```
- (void)insertRecord:(NSString *)record {
    dispatch__barrier_sync(CUSTOM_DB_QUEUE, ^{
        // original code to insert record
    };
}
```

And your `getRecord` method becomes:

```
- (Record *)getRecord {
    __block Record *result = nil;

    dispatch_sync(CUSTOM_DB_QUEUE, ^{
        // original code that sets result
    };

    return result;
}
```

By using `dispatch_sync` and `dispatch_barrier_sync`, this code allows for any number of concurrent calls to `getRecord` but only one call to `insertRecord`. It also ensures calls to `getRecord` are blocked while `insertRecord:` is being run.

Comment: Thanks so much, but when i try to modify the getRecord function as you recommend, the codes inside dispatch_sync works fine. but after that it didnt return the result. any idea?

Comment: Are setting and returning the __block variable?

Comment: oh, i got it, cause i called another function which is dispatch_sync with the same queue too. What a stupid mistake, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

To make it thread safe, you can use `pthread_mutex_t` as a global instance. Lock/unlock this mutex according to its usage
e.g.

```
pthread_mutex_t *dbLock;

Class A
pthread_mutex_lock(dbLock);

[[DBManager getInstance] insertRecord:@"12345"];

pthread_mutex_unlock(dbLock);

Class B
-(void)processData{
    pthread_mutex_lock(dbLock);

    Record r = [[DBManager getInstance] getRecord];
    // working with record r. after that doing some layout update
    [self.lbTitle setText:r.name];

    pthread_mutex_unlock(dbLock);
}
```